# How can I redirect to a new tab with some href URL and with a search cookie/parameter which can give some value like ID or account number?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

**Example :**Building an extension which redirect to new tab when click on button or link with URL and with some search cookies or parameter which can give value at URL bar like id or account no.

Something like this:1) `https://example.com/index?id=1`
2) `https://example.com/index?account_no=2220`

Comment: Please inform what have you tried so far and what are the main difficulties

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.